# How to close the filepicker.io widget?

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

When using filepicker.io is there a function in the API to close the widget properly or do we need to trigger a click on the `x` link or on the background?

We want to detect when user presses <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and close the widget when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no api call to close the modal. Feel free to trigger the click event on the x.

Comment: On the other hand, having `esc` close the modal makes sense and we'll probably just put that in the main branch at some point in the next couple weeks.

Comment: Oh great, I'll wait for the update on this one and trigger the click for the moment. Will pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> lead to the onError() being called?

Comment: I needed to close the filepicker on state change in angular. My solution was to trigger a click on the close button as noted above.
`$('.fp__close').trigger('click');`